# HTML5 video - Safari doesn't play past second video

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari

what I'm trying to do is have 4 videos play in sequential order automatically. When one ends, the next begins, until the last video. What I have so far works as intended in every browser except Safari. In safari, it loads the first video (00.mp4), successfully switches to the second video (01.mp4), and that's it, no more. Here's what I got, I'm sort of figuring this stuff out as I go so sorry if my code is terrible and inefficient.

This is my javascript:

```
function load() {
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
       if (video.canPlayType("video/ogg")) {
            video.src='00.ogg';
            video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
            video.src='01.ogg';
                video.load();
                video.removeEventListener('ended', arguments.callee, false);
                video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                    video.removeEventListener('ended', arguments.callee, false);
                    video.src='02.ogg';
                    video.load();
                    video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                        video.removeEventListener('ended', arguments.callee, false);
                        video.src='08.ogg';
                        video.load();
                    }, false);
                }, false);
            }, false);
       }
       else if (video.canPlayType("video/mp4")) {
           video.src='00.mp4';
           video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                video.src='01.mp4';
                video.load();
                video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                    video.src='02.mp4';
                    video.load();
                    video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                        video.src='08.mp4';
                        video.load();
                    }, false);
                }, false);
            }, false);
       }
       else {
           window.alert("Blah blah placeholder blah");
       }
}
```

and this is the relevant HTML:

```
<body onLoad="load()">
<video id="vid" autoplay width="416" height="240" src=""></video>
```

Any corrections for what I assume is awful coding is also appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Same exact issue.  I noticed that if you use the controls to jump to another place in the video, Safari correctly loads the next video fine

```
<video autoplay=true width=100% height=100% controls="controls" id=theVideo onended="end(this)" style=position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px >
<source src="Opening.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script>

function end(inVideoEnded)
{
 var video = document.getElementById("theVideo");
 if (playstate == 0) {
   video.src = "Choice1-H.264 for iPod video and iPhone 640x480.m4v";
   playstate=1;
 } else if (playstate == 1) {
   video.src = "Choice1_A-H.264 for iPod video and iPhone 640x480.m4v";
   playstate=2;
 } else if (playstate == 2) {
   video.src = "Choice1_B-H.264 for iPod video and iPhone 640x480.m4v";
   playstate=3;
 } else if (playstate == 3) {
   video.src = "Choice1_C-H.264 for iPod video and iPhone 640x480.m4v";
   playstate=4;
 }
 video.load();
 video.play();
 video.onended = function(e) {
  end(e);
 }
}

</script>
</code>
```

I added the setTimeout line.  This jumps it back to start after 100 milliseconds and that was enough time for my Safari to consider it enough to play a second video.  50 milliseconds was too short.  Try adding a line like that right after your video.load

```
  video.load();
  video.play();

  setTimeout("document.getElementById('theVideo').currentTime = 0;",100);

  video.onended = function(e) {
    end(e);
  } 
}
```